# What is the best practice to start a process in docker image, when single image can behave differently (web/worker)

Tags: docker

I have a node.js based application and my original Dockerfile looks like,

```
WORKDIR /app

COPY dist /app/

CMD pm2 start index.js && pm2 logs
```

Now, I want to use the same image to run a worker by only changing the command to `pm2 start scheduler`.

I'm thinking about removing the `CMD` from the docker image and execute the startup script separately.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can override the `CMD` with a Docker Compose `command:` or by putting a command after the image name in `docker run`.  But your image should have a sensible default `CMD` for whatever you think is the "most likely" thing you're going to do with it.

Comment: Oh okay. I'm using AWS ECS to run the container, so I think I can pass the alternate command there for the worker. Thank you!